# How can I get a dataset from a graph in a website using dev tools and Python?

Tags: python, php, web-scraping, graph, data-science

I am trying to get a certain graph from this url: 
https://sasri.sasa.org.za/agronomy/mycanesimlite/mcl_single_run_get_input.php?start_date=2021-06-15&harvest_date=2022-06-15&ratoon=R&residue=0&tam=150&irrigation=Rainfed&weather_station=14&forecast=Normal 
When you inspect the website, you can find the following link to a php file that, supposedly, generates a graph. That's the graph Im trying to get. 
https://sasri.sasa.org.za/agronomy/mycanesimlite/mcl_crop_status_data.php

This is the code I am currently using. By the way, It's obviously Python

```
import requests

actionURL = "https://sasri.sasa.org.za/agronomy/mycanesimlite/mcl_crop_status_data.php"

res = requests.get(actionURL)

cookies = res.cookies

post_data = {"method":"POST"}

headers = {
                "Host": "sasri.sasa.org.za",
                "Connection": "keep-alive",
                "Accept": "*/*",
                "Origin": "https://sarsi.sasa.org.za",
                "Sec-Fetch-Dest":"empty",
                "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
                "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
                "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:102.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/102.0",
                "sec-ch-ua-platform": "Linux",
                "Content-Length": "38",
                "Origin": "https://sasri.sasa.org.za",
                "Referer": "https://sasri.sasa.org.za/agronomy/mycanesimlite/mcl_single_run_get_input.php?start_date=2021-06-15&harvest_date=2022-06-15&ratoon=R&residue=0&tam=150&irrigation=Rainfed&weather_station=14&forecast=Normal",
                "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
                "Accept-Language": "es-ES,es;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3",
                "Cookie": "ga=GA1.3.669250053.1658240582; _gid=GA1.3.65875213.1658240582; _gat=1; PHPSESSID=62d6be5ae92de",
                "Sec-Fetch-Site": "same-origin",
                "Sec-Fetch-Mode": "cors"
}

res_post = requests.post(actionURL, data=post_data, cookies=cookies, headers=headers)

values = res_post.json()

print(values)
```

However, when I execute it, I get the following error

```
'\nNotice: Undefined index: field in D:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\Client\\sasa\\Sasex\\Apps\\MyCanesim_Lite\\mcl_crop_status_data.php on line 18\n[] \r\n'
```

By the way, this happens to me when I'm using chrome. When I use Firefox, this whole issue seems to be different as I still cannot retrieve the data, but I can click on the previous link and that php errors disappears.

Comment: Your PHP file needs to be fixed. Why do you post the python code?

Comment: Yeah I suspected that it had to do with the PHP code. Sadly, since I don't have access to the PHP file, as it is hosted on a web server I don't have access to, I cannot fix that. I posted the Python code because there may had been a problem in the headers or something like the Request type. I tried to provide as much information as I could about the problem. Thanks for the help anyway. That means the error is not mine and I would need to email the org. that developed the page.

Comment: Yes, because if you run the action URL within any browser you'll see the same error output clearly coming from bad PHP coding (using an index of an array which does not exist).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check again all information in `DevTool` - especialy request/post data.

It has to be

```py
post_data = {
    "field": "E42BA003699D9570E053B70110AC1F1D"
}
```

---

**EDIT:**

Code works for me even without headers and cookies

```py
import requests

url = "https://sasri.sasa.org.za/agronomy/mycanesimlite/mcl_crop_status_data.php"

payload = {"field": "E42BA003699D9570E053B70110AC1F1D"}

response = requests.post(url, data=payload)

data = response.json()

print(data)
```

---

On this page is also link to the same data but in CSV file - and this file has also `E42BA003699D9570E053B70110AC1F1D` in its name.

```py
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://sasri.sasa.org.za/agronomy/mycanesimlite/Daily_dataE42BA003699D9570E053B70110AC1F1D.csv'

df = pd.read_csv(url)

print(df)
```

---

**EDIT:**

Page can use different value `field` in every execution but in source code I found

```
<input type='hidden' value='E42BA003699D9570E053B70110AC1F1D'  id='field_hidden'/>
```

and this code uses `BeautifulSoup` to get this value from HTML.

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# --- field ---

url = "https://sasri.sasa.org.za/agronomy/mycanesimlite/mcl_single_run_get_input.php?start_date=2021-06-15&harvest_date=2022-06-15&ratoon=R&residue=0&tam=150&irrigation=Rainfed&weather_station=14&forecast=Normal"

response = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")

field = soup.find("input", {"id": "field_hidden"})

print('field:', field['value'])

# --- JSON data ---

url = "https://sasri.sasa.org.za/agronomy/mycanesimlite/mcl_crop_status_data.php"

payload = {"field": field['value']}  # <--- value from field

response = requests.post(url, data=payload)

data = response.json()

print(data)

# --- CSV data ---

import pandas as pd

url = 'https://sasri.sasa.org.za/agronomy/mycanesimlite/Daily_data{}.csv'.format(field['value'])  # <--- value from field

df = pd.read_csv(url)

print(df)
```

Comment: Thank you, It now works. I am not totally sure why, but It does, and It works for me.

Comment: it works because it needed value `E42BA003699D9570E053B70110AC1F1D` to send correct data. But on page there is also link to the same data as `CSV` - and this link also has `E42BA003699D9570E053B70110AC1F1D`

Comment: I added code which reads csv directly to pandas

Comment: Thank you again. Btw, how did you find that link in particular

Comment: And also @furas , I have realized that this identifier changes each time the request.get is executed. Do you know how to get that values from the data form

Comment: using standard function `find` in browser/editor (with value `E42BA003699D9570E053B70110AC1F1D`)  I found in source code `<input type='hidden' value='E42BA003699D9570E053B70110AC1F1D' ...>` and you can `.get()` page and use `beautifulsoup` or `lxml` to search data in HTML. Eventually you can try to do this with `regex`. I will put code later.

Comment: I added code which search this value in HTML.